# метод POST посредством javascript

Tags: javascript, post

Пытаюсь реализовать метод POST, который будет отправлять данные на сервер. Данные, в свою очередь, вводятся в поля формы. Форма передается в качестве параметра функции, в которой реализуется POST

```
<div class="modal" id="modalDialog">
<form name="modalwindowpush">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="content">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Закрыть" onclick="modal_close()">
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить" onclick="add_element() && add_post(modalwindowpush)">
```

Сама функция

```
function add_post(obj) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var body = "title=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.title) + "&content=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.content);
        req.open("POST", 'PushNewsServlet', true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.send(body);
    }
```

Но в итоге данные не отправляются на сервер... 
   Выдает ошибку 405

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не отправляются?

Comment: открываю базу в PostgeSQL и вижу, что новая строка не появилась. До этого, когда я реализовывал POST через чистый html, я в базе видел изменения

Comment: В консоле хрома во вкладке `Network` видишь запись об оправке запроса?

Comment: вижу 405 ошибку

Comment: добавь эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, а почему ты думаешь, что у тебя должен быть метод `POST`?

Comment: ... признаться, не совсем понял...

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев, отправка формы это не всегда `POST`. Если в теге form не указан атрибут `method`, то при обычном submit будет отправлен `GET` запрос. Следовательно, если сервер ожидает именно GET запрос - то ты и будешь получать ошибку пытаясь отправить POST

Comment: Понятно теперь. Хотя добавил в form метод post, но не помогло